# From dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss +tz to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am currently working with dates in SQL Server whose datatype is NVARCHAR(max) and whose format is dd-mm-yy hh:mm:ss +tz, meaning they look like this:

> 31-10-18 18:34:05 +00:00

And, despite all my efforts, I couldn't find a way to convert those dates to datetimes whereas I used all sorts of combinations with the CAST and CONVERT functions.

Most of the time, I had the following error message:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

And I'm pretty sure it comes from the fact that the year is written as '18' instead of '2018'.

I would therefore like to find the simplest way to perform such a conversion.

Comment: Do all dates have +00:00 timezone? And what is the datatype you want? datetime? datetime2? datetimeoffset?

Comment: Hi Salman. Yes, it's +00:00 everywhere. And I want a datetime datatype.

Comment: I've posted an answer which (i) ignores the offset (ii) uses datetimeoffset type to include the offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set date format before

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT CAST('31-10-18 18:34:05 +00:00' as datetimeoffset)
```

Result

```
----------------------------------
2018-10-31 18:34:05.0000000 +00:00
```

Comment: `SET DATEFORMAT dmy; SELECT CAST('31-10-18 18:34:05 +00:00' as datetime)` is therefore my solution. Thank you for that trick!